# Best way to create icon for UI , based on 3d model player can use in game

Tags: unity, gui

I'm trying to figure the best way to create icon (for UI) from my 3d model (object) that player can use in the game. 
Maybe this is a silly question, but: how do you create icon ? 
Do you create a new scene, place object and use a "shift-print" to take screenshots ?

Others way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be a comment, but I want to post a screen shot. I have used the model preview screen to do screen grab in the past. You can move the model around in all 3 axis with your mouse.

[image]

Comment: And you take a screenshot then elaborate it ?

Comment: Yes. Screen shot, Gimp, clean up the background, brighten it up a bit. Whatever you need.